# I have updated my plugins, though one page of the site has 'hit a critical error'

Tags: plugins, child-theme

I am the main user/access of this site.

I updated our plugins and themes. Everything was successful, though only ONE page of the entire website has hit a 'critical error'.

It appears to have lost margining and displays not images like the other pages. The posts within the pages are okay.

We use Cornerstone for the editing. I have noticed that the pages that are not working use HTML as their Editing option. This has always been the case; though why have they not carried across, perfectly, like the other pages following the update?

The developer told me why he saved the page like this.

"*I didn't set up the Portfolio pages in Cornerstone because they're meant to automatically gather the posts from a particular category and display them. Cornerstone doesn't have this ability, unless you do it manually each time you create a new row of posts (Cornerstone only allows one row at a time)*."

Changing the page to Cornerstone also does not work. It reverts to HTML. This page's user interface is no different to the other pages, so the setting should not be different.

Would it be a 'Site-ground' thing to solve, perhaps?

Child Theme X is our page theme.  Also updated.

Comment: What's Site-ground? Do you have a backup of the site before the update?

Comment: There should also be details of the critical error, either emailed to the site admin (you?) or in the server logs. However I'd suggest restoring from backup or downgrading plugins etc. back to the same versions that last worked first.

Comment: @Rup siteground is the hosting provider. Simon, check your PHP error log, you'll need to get in touch with the plugin that's responsible. You may need to undo your update then update each item individually, checking the page to see if its broken as you go along. Otherwise it's not possible to write a solution to this question as you do not know what the problem is, and 3rd party plugin dev/user support is not in this stacks scope